# Place custom button to go back between screens with SwiftUI compatible with iOS13

Tags: swift, swiftui, uinavigationcontroller

I want to create my own button that allows me to go back to a previous screen without using the default NavigationBar, doing research I have seen people who use @Environment but it is not compatible with iOS 13, I would also need a functionality that allows me to make x amount of screens

That's what I have:

```
struct KnowMoreView: View {
  // MARK: - PROPERTY
  
  // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
      ZStack {
        Color.white
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        Color(UIColor.ray239)
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        VStack {
          LabeledHeaderView(label: "know_more_about_us".localized, showBackButton: true) {
            // Here goes the back method
          }
          Divider()
            .frame(height: 2)
            .overlay(Color("gray151"))
            .padding(.top, -10)
          Image("knowMore")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .padding(.top, 12)
            .cornerRadius(24)
          
          Text("explore_my_fund".localized.uppercased())
            .foregroundColor(Color("gray143"))
            .font(.custom(Fonts.GothamMedium.rawValue, size: 24))
            .padding(.top, 12)
          
          HStack {
            Spacer()
            
            SquareButton(label: "who_we_are".localized, image: "whoWeAre", action: {
              
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            SquareButton(label: "faqs".localized, image: "faqs", action: {
              
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            SquareButton(label: "our_products".localized, image: "ourProducts", action: {
              
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
          }
          .padding(.top, 12)
          
          Spacer()
        }
      }
      .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      .background(BackButtonHandler { })
    }
}
```

Header:

```
struct LabeledHeaderView: View {
  
  // MARK: - PROPERTY
  let label: String
  var showBackButton: Bool
  let action: () -> Void
  
  // MARK: - BODY
    var body: some View {
      ZStack {
        Color.white
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        VStack {
          
          Image("fullLogo")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 270)
            .padding(.bottom, 18)
            .padding(.top, 6)
          
          HStack {
            if showBackButton {
              Button(action: {
                action()
              }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                  .resizable()
                  .foregroundColor(Color("gray81"))
                  .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                  .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                
              }
              .padding(.leading, 16)
              .padding(.trailing, -30)
            } else {
              Spacer()
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Text(label)
              .foregroundColor(Color("gray81"))
              .font(.custom(Fonts.AtleticoRegular.rawValue, size: 20))
              .bold()
            Spacer()
          }
          .padding(.bottom, 18)
        }
      }
      .frame(height: 120)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a whole lot of UI code here but no real context on your setup. How do you navigate forward? Why does "presentation mode" not work? SwiftUI was in its infancy for iOS 13 it is very limited

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the code below,

```
 struct KnowMoreView: View {

    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
             Color.white
              .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        Color(UIColor.ray239)
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
        VStack {
          LabeledHeaderView(label: "know_more_about_us".localized, showBackButton: true) {
            // Here goes the back method
          }
          Divider()
            .frame(height: 2)
            .overlay(Color("gray151"))
            .padding(.top, -10)
          Image("knowMore")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            .padding(.top, 12)
            .cornerRadius(24)
          
          Text("explore_my_fund".localized.uppercased())
            .foregroundColor(Color("gray143"))
            .font(.custom(Fonts.GothamMedium.rawValue, size: 24))
            .padding(.top, 12)
          
          HStack {
            Spacer()
            
            SquareButton(label: "who_we_are".localized, image: "whoWeAre", action: {
              
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            SquareButton(label: "faqs".localized, image: "faqs", action: {
              
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            SquareButton(label: "our_products".localized, image: "ourProducts", action: {
              
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
          }
          .padding(.top, 12)
          
          Spacer()
        }
      }
      .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
      .navigationBarItems(leading: backButton)
    }

}

    var backButton: some View {
            Button(action: {
                self.dismiss()
            }) {
                HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("Back")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.leading, 2)
                }
                .padding(.leading, -4.0)
            }
        }
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).